# Dereferencing not working for smart pointer in set

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
template <typename T>
/* Simple smart pointer class */
class SmartPtr
{
    T *ptr;
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(T *p = NULL) { ptr = p; }
    ~SmartPtr() { delete(ptr); }
    T & operator * () { return *ptr; }

    T * operator -> () { return ptr; }

};

class simple {

private:
    int x;
public:
    simple(int y = 0) :x(y) {}
    int getX() { return x; }
};
typedef SmartPtr<simple> simplePtr;



int main() {


    std::set<simplePtr> st;
    simplePtr p1 = simplePtr(new simple(5));
    simplePtr p2 = simplePtr(new simple(5));
    simplePtr p3 = simplePtr(new simple(5));
    simplePtr p4 = simplePtr(new simple(5));

    std::cout << p1->getX();  <-- working fine
    st.insert(p1);
    st.insert(p2);
    st.insert(p3);
    st.insert(p4);

    for (std::set<simplePtr>::iterator it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->getX();  // Not working??
    }
}
```

Compilation is failed with error in Visual Studio 2013:

```
Error   C2039   getX: is not a member of SmartPtr<simple>
```

On linux:

```
error: ‘const class SmartPtr<simple>’ has no member named ‘getX’
```

Is this a problem with iterator??

Comment: Once you've solved your syntax issue, do take care of fixing your copy- and move- constructors and assignment operators : as it is now, every `SmartPtr` pointing to the same object will try to delete it. The first one will invalidate all of the others, and the second one will trigger UB from double deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `it->getX()` as a syntactic sugar for `(*it).getX()`. [In principle, a class can overload the `->` and `*` (dereferencing) operators inconsistently, but `std::set<T>::iterator`,  unsurprisingly, doesn't break that convention]. So, in your case, `*it` is dereferenced to an lvalue of type `const SmartPtr<simple>&`, and the `.getX()` applied to it fails, because `SmartPtr` doesn't have a `getX()` method. Since, instead you mean to access the object that the obtained `SmartPtr` points to, you must add one more level of dereferencing:

> #### Correction 1
>
> Replace `it->getX()` with `(**it).getX()` or `(*it)->getX()`.

There is still another problem, though - `*it` results in a **`const`** `SmartPtr` (yes, `std::set`'s non-constant iterator doesn't provide write access to the container's elements, otherwise you could break correct ordering of elements in the container). But both `->` and `*` (dereferencing) operators in `SmartPtr` are defined in such a way that they can be invoked only on non-`const` objects. To fix that, you must make those two functions `const`:

> #### Correction 2 (in `SmartPtr<T>`)
>
> ```
> //                 vvvvv
> T & operator * ()  const { return *ptr; }
> T * operator -> () const { return ptr; }
> //                 ^^^^^
> ```

After you make this second correction, you can replace your old-style for-loop with a range-for loop:

```
for (const simplePtr& p : st)
{
    std::cout << p->getX();
}
```

Still, your program will not compile - `SmartPtr<T>` objects cannot be put in an `std::set` since they are not *comparable*. Fix that by defining `operator<()`:

> #### Correction 3
>
> Add to `SmartPtr<T>`:
>
> ```
> bool operator<(const SmartPtr& other) const { return ptr < other.ptr; }
> ```

At this point your code will compile but chances are high that it will not work correctly. The reason is that the copy-semantics of `SmartPtr<T>` is left to compiler's discretion which fails to meet your intent. This is easy to guess by spotting the violation of the [Rule of Three, Four and Five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782927/6394138) - your class defines the destructor but fails to define the copy and/or move constructor and the assignment operator. As a result your code performs double deletion and therefore cannot be guaranteed any well defined behavior.

> #### Correction 4
>
> Fix the copy semantics of `SmartPtr<T>`.

I "fixed" your code by assigning move semantics to `SmartPtr` (this required adding `std::move()` when `insert()`-ing it into `std::set`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

template <typename T>
class SmartPtr
{
    T *ptr;
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(T *p = NULL) { ptr = p; }
    ~SmartPtr() { delete(ptr); }
    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& other) = delete;
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr&& other) : ptr(other.ptr) { other.ptr = NULL; }
    SmartPtr& operator=(SmartPtr other)
    {
        std::swap(ptr, other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T & operator * () const { return *ptr; }
    T * operator -> () const { return ptr; }

    bool operator<(const SmartPtr& other) const { return ptr < other.ptr; }
};

class simple {
    int x;
public:
    simple(int y = 0) : x(y) {}
    int getX() { return x; }
};
typedef SmartPtr<simple> simplePtr;

int main() {
    std::set<simplePtr> st;
    simplePtr p1 = simplePtr(new simple(5));
    simplePtr p2 = simplePtr(new simple(5));

    st.insert(std::move(p1));
    st.insert(std::move(p2));

    for (const simplePtr& p : st)
    {
        std::cout << p->getX();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Shan Your `SmartPtr` has a number of problems unrelated to your question. See updated answer.

Comment: I just want to know that why it's not working when i am inserting it to set.Because of move semantics ??

Comment: @Shan I elaborated my answer.

Comment: Thumbs up for explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator needs to be dereferenced, at which point you get a pointer. Which then needs to be dereferenced.  So:

```
    std::cout << (*it)->getX();
```

Comment: @Shan: Your next issue is that you need to write `int getX() const {...}`.  Note the `const`.  Read about const methods...you can't modify elements inside a set generally, because it might change their ordering.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have to define `operator <` for the class `SmartPtr` before using it in the set.

Secondly you have to declare the member function  `getX` like

```
int getX() const { return x; }
```

And you have to write at least like

```
std::cout << ( *it )->getX();
```